# Get item from order id

Tags: orders, magento-1

My order #100000010 has 3 items. But when I used this code, it did not echo anything. Where is my mistake

```
<?php   
$id_order = 100000010;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id_order);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $i):
  echo $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($i->getProductId())->getSku();
endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi 100000010 is order increment id.it is not order id..
So need to change

to

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id_order)
```

from

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id_order);
```

Answer (score 4):

The long number is the order's `increment_id`, which is different from its `entity_id` (which is what `load()` expects).

Use `loadByIncrementId()` to load by increment ID:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id_order);
```