# Send emails after the order was placed - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, payment-methods

I want to have the following function in my store, I have two payments methods: CC and Bank Transfer Payment

1. if the CC method was used, after the order was placed I need to send one email to the vendor company with product name and quantity. For vendor we can use a attribute that will contain email for each vendor in part.

   2. If Bank Transfer Payment was used, then we need to have a button in the back-end in order to can start the same action but manually.

How I can do something like this? Someone can point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not give you full code, But I will guide you step by step

Use this event in this event you will get all data related to order

```
sales_order_place_after
```

Here is the example of code how to use this event

[Not triggering sales_order_place_after observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104996/not-triggering-sales-order-place-after-observer)

Get order item from order and from order item load product and get supplier data from your product

you can use this thread for this

[Get item from order id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66922/get-item-from-order-id)

you don't have to load `$order` you already have that in event.

Write code to send email here is the code how to write code to send email

[How to send email using magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85373/how-to-send-email-using-magento)

Comment: thank you I have a idea too, but I need some code here if you can help will be perfect, thank you

Comment: from above three point, which code you want from my side

Comment: tell me again please, I don't understand very well

Comment: I have given three steps in my answer create event, get product data, and send email, for what you want code from the above

Comment: for example what I can do to check if the payment method is CC, how I can check if the product contain nokia for example attribute and if yes then select it and send email, how I can add the backend button in the orders if the payment method is Bank Transfer Payment

Comment: okay, I see that you don't want to help me with this, thank you anyway.